# Rails3: Appropriate use of routing and resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've recently joined the world of Rails app development (Rails3) and I may be abusing resourceful routing.

The default resourceful routing makes some really convenient helper methods for the URLs which I use constantly.  My problem is that I have controllers that I specified the routing as resourceful simply to take advantage of those helper methods.  I have some basic site navigation that has no business with resources.

```
resource :home do
  member do
    get 'main'
    get 'about'
    get 'login'
    get 'help'
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do what I've been doing?  Anything that doesn't require that I manually add routing entries each time I have a new controller action?

Just to clarify, I want to specify routing for a controller without having to explicitly add any new actions but I also want it to auto-generate helper methods.  So far, I have to explicitly add routes for each action I want that for.  I can get something similar by doing this (in a non-resourceful way),

```
match 'home/about' => 'home#about'
```

But I don't want to have to write that very every route that doesn't fall into the convention.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but it sounds as though you want it to automatically look through your controller for public methods, and create named routes for them. Am I reading that right? If so, it seems like you are asking for a kind of magic that even Rails can't supply.

Comment: No, I think you have it right.  To make an example, having a line like "match ':controller(/:action)'" automagically detect the actions of the controller and generate named routes.  I'm still learning what sort of tricks rails has available.  On the other hand, I wouldn't mind someone recommending a better approach or giving some examples of how they commonly do this for their apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into your controller for public instance methods and generate routes automatically.

```
# routes.rb
HomeController.public_instance_methods(false).select{|m| !(m.to_s =~ /^_/)}.each do |m|
  match "home/#{m}", :action => m, :controller => HomeController, :as => "home_#{m}"
end
```

This will take the explicit(non-inherited) public instance methods from your controller, and select the ones that **don't** begin with an underscore(because underscored ones are generated methods for filters, the rest are actual actions). Then it will generate a named route for each.

Keep in mind that `routes.rb` is processed only at server startup so you will have to restart the server after you add new actions.

Comment: That's what I was just looking into now.  Not to press you further but how could this be done in a more generic way so I can pass it any controller name?  For example (assuming it's calling the method you defined), generate_named_routes :home.  I was trying to figure out if there was code in Rails already that could take :home and turn it into HomeController.  Then it would be simple to have a generalized method for generating named routes.

Comment: Try `"#{my_symbol.to_s.classify}Controller".constantize` to convert a symbol into its corresponding controller class. you can put that class in a variable and use it instead of directly specifying the controller as above.

Comment: Thanks for the direction!  I did end up doing this but to add to my tale, I had one terrible oversight.  This relies on an action method being present on the controller.  In some instances, I have a view that has no action method defined for it...I'm falling back on Rails' auto-mapping of views.  If I wanted to take this further, I'd have to do some sniffing of views, action methods, etc.  Can o' worms.  Suddenly, it's easy just to use "match 'home/about'".  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another simpler one. Just add a generic route to the bottom of your `routes.rb`

```
match ":controller/:action"
```

and it will map directly to the specified action of the specified controller. You can be a bit more specific if you like. For example, using `get` instead of `match` to restrict to HTTP GET requests, specifying the applicaple controllers etc.

```
get ":controller/:action", :constraints => { :controller => /home|help/ }
```